# How to register document type which iOS safari should support?

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, info.plist, cfbundleidentifier

Im working on an iOS application which has file extenstion e.g. `.vlin` and i want iOS device to recognize this extension. So far I am able to achieve following

- `.vlin` is supported in iphone native mail client
- clicking `.vlin` file opens in my `Vlin` app.

I am using cordova and added config settings in config.xml

But somehow it is not working for iOS safari browser. If i try to open file in iOS safari it open in the browser itself as a text file.
I want it to open in my `Vlin` iOS app.

My info.plist and config.xml code is:

```
<platform name="ios">        
<preference name="IosLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIFileSharingEnabled">
    <true />
</config-file> 
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleDocumentTypes">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UTExportedTypeDeclarations">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Vlin document</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>vlin</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>  
</config-file>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

- info.plist

  ```
      <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
      <true/>
      <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
          <string>Editor</string>
          <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
          <string>Owner</string>
          <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
          <array>
            <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </array>
      <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
          <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
          </array>
          <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
          <string>Vlin document</string>
          <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
          <string>com.example.vlin.vlin</string>
          <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
          <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>vlin</string>
          </dict>
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  ```

sample file format: `invite.vlin`

```
{
 "invite”: {
  "name": “Some College",
  "identifier": “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
 },
 “value”: “xxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample .vlin file?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Just added sample file format `invite.vlin`.

Comment: I meant a real .vlin file uploaded somewher, just to check how browsers are "seeing" it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2:

Your real problem is that safari sees your .vlin file as a text file and won't give you the option to open it in another application, maybe if you configure the server properly to serve it as `com.example.vlin.vlin` or maybe as `application/json` it should show you the open with dialog.

As an example, you can test this .vlin file on my server.

http://jcesarmobile.byethost33.com/test4.vlin

It's not a real .vlin file, it's a .vlin file zipped and renamed to .vlin and safari shows the open with dialog

EDIT:

Not sure why people is downvoting, config-file tag from config.xml is not implemented, see [the issue to implement it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11968).

Original answer:

You can't use config-file tag inside the config.xml yet (it's being worked on, but not finished).

You can use it on the plugin.xml, so you have to create a "dumb" plugin that just have the plugin.xml with those tags on it.

You can take a look into this plugin that just uses the plugin.xml to write into the Info.plist
https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security

Comment: thanks for answering but this is not solving my problem :)

Comment: can you share the plugin you created to do it? are those values added into the info.plist?

Comment: No, I didn't created plugin as we only do add config to info.plist. all above configs are added to info.plist using config.xml and working for files which are on device. If i mail .vlin file to iphone device it is working but not working if i try to download .vlin file from ios safari browser actually from any browser.

Comment: just added info.plist entries

Comment: so you say it works from config.xml? which cordova CLI and cordova-ios versions are you using?

Comment: cordova version 6.3.1

Comment: and cordova-ios? it's really strange, as far as I know we have not finish implementing that feature and it doesn't work for me if I add that to my config.xml

Comment: BTW, if you download the file on safari it won't open on any app, but it should display a dialog on top with an "Open with" button where your app should be shown.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it shows open with for other extensions like .pdf/.doc but not for mine which is .vlin :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125195/discussion-between-pradeep1991singh-and-jcesarmobile).